# How to search in the GQL Viewer in appengine dashboard by key?

Tags: google-app-engine

How to search in the GQL Viewer in appengine dashboard by key?

I use this and it gives an error:

```
SELECT * FROM Cache where __key__ = KEY('Cache', 'ag9wYWdhbGd1eS1zdGF0aWNyHAsSBUNhY2hlIhEvYnV0dG9ucy9lZGl0LmdpZgw ')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What error?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998084/how-do-i-query-in-gql-using-the-entity-key/1999747#1999747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in what looks like an encoded key as a key name. Try "KEY('ag9wYWdhbGd1eS1zdGF0aWNyHAsSBUNhY2hlIhEvYnV0dG9ucy9lZGl0LmdpZgw')" instead.

Comment: I tried this as well. It works fine in the code but doesn't work in the GQL Dashboard. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be important to use single quotes. This seems to work:

```
SELECT * FROM Cache where __key__ = KEY('ag9wYWdhbGd1eS1zdGF0aWNyHAsSBUNhY2hlIhEvYnV0dG9ucy9lZGl0LmdpZgw ')
```